# Terminal aborts installation of a package no matter what I type

Tags: command-line, package-management, 13.04

When I'm trying to install a package, say `chromium` I type this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium
```

Then it says:

```
After this operation, 3.1415926 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Then when I type in `yes` or `y` or `Y` or whatever I tried everything but no matter what I type it shows up like this:

```
Abort.
```

I just did a clean installation of 13.04 yesterday and didn't have this problem before when I was using 12.04 ( `y` always works ).  How do I fix it?

By the way LXTerminal doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Did you `apt-get install -f`?

Comment: I did that but the problem's still there :(

Comment: Can you install software via Software Center or Synaptic?

Comment: yep, no problem there.

Comment: You said LXTerminal doesn't have the problem, in which terminal does the problem occur?

Comment: The Default terminal of ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Tried reinstalling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

`sudo apt-get -y install chromium-browser`

Comment: Well after a system update it miraculously worked.  Thanks for the answer!